# Web workers inside promise causing crash

Tags: javascript, multithreading, google-chrome, promise, web-worker

The expected workflow of my code is getting the data from `getData`.

`getData` calls the worker that will do `ImageUtil.getHex` on the input. `ImageUtil.getHex` is a heavy function that needs to iterate every pixel of an image area `area`, so that's why I want to create it runs in the background and done in multithreading. The function is also independent, which I guess is a good candidate to put in the worker.

This is the chunk of code that needs the `getData` function:

```
class Mosaic {
    // ...
  build() {
    for (let y = 0; y < canvas.height; y += options.tileHeight) {
      for (let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += options.tileWidth) {
        //... some code here
        // imgContext: a context of a canvas containing the image
        let area = imgContext.getImageData(x, y, w, h);
        this.getData(area, x, y)
          .then((data) => {
              // do something with data
            });
        //... 
      }
    }
  // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

this is the getData function:

```
getData(data, x, y) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let worker = new Worker('js/worker.js');
    worker.onmessage = (e) => {
      let hex = e.data;
      let img = new Image();
      let loc = `image/${hex}`
      img.onload = (e) => {
        resolve({
          hex: hex,
          x: x,
          y: y
        });
      }
      img.src = loc;
    }
    worker.postMessage(data);
  });
```

js/worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  let hex = ImageUtil.getHex(e.data); // another function
  self.postMessage(hex);
  self.close();
}, false);

class ImageUtil {
  static getHex(imgData) {
    let data = imgData.data;
    let r = 0,
        g = 0,
        b = 0,

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
      // count rgb here
    }

    let count = data.length / 4;
    r = ("0" + (Math.floor(r / count)).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    g = ("0" + (Math.floor(g / count)).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    b = ("0" + (Math.floor(b / count)).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    let hex = `${r}${g}${b}`;
    return hex;
  }
}
```

The problem is, when ran, it makes the browser crash. Even if it's not crashing, the performance is much slower than without using worker.

Steps to reproduce:

1. The other part of the code that isn't mentioned here create a
   `Mosaic` object. Then, we call `build()` on that Mosaic object.
2. Crash

I think I misunderstood the way of workers work. Is it the right way, and how do I fix the code so it won't crash anymore?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `ImageUtil` imported into `Worker`? Is `hex` posted to main thread? Is `getData` called more than once?

Comment: @guest271314 I just added `ImageUtil` to the question, thanks! I guess `hex` is posted to the main thread. `getData` is called more than once, it's in an iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `makeTile` within a nested `for` loop, where `makeTile` creates `worker`. You are creating 950 `Worker` instances. Each `Worker` instance calls `postMessage`. That is the reason the browser is crashing.

You need to adjust you scripts to handle arrays of promises, instead of a single `Promise`. `worker.js` should be called once, not 950 times.

You can create an array before the `for` loops, pass the data as an array to `Promise.resolve()`

```
  var arr = [];
  for (let y = 0; y < canvas.height; y += options.tileHeight) {
    for (let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += options.tileWidth) {
      let areaData = imgContext
                     .getImageData(x, y, options.tileWidth, options.tileHeight);
      arr.push(Promise.resolve([areaData, x, y]))
    }
  };
```

then after the `for` loops use `Promise.all()` to process the data

```
Promise.all(arr.map(function(tile) {
   this.makeTile(/* tile data here */) // make necessary changes at `makeTile`
   .then(function(tiles) {
     // do stuff with `tiles` array

   })
}))
```

Move

```
let worker = new Worker('worker.js');
```

outside of `makeTile()`, or create logic so that the call is only made once.

Similarly, at `worker.js`, adjust the script to handle an array of data, instead of a single value.

When `message` event is fired at main thread, process the data as an array of values.

The gist of the solution is to refactor your code base to handle arrays, and arrays of promises; both at main thread and at `worker.js`; with the object being to call `worker.js` at most once at `change`
event of `<input type="file">` element. Where a single `message` is posted to `Worker`, and single `message` event is expected from `Worker`. Then do stuff with the returned array containing the processed data.

Comment: Isn't to close the `Worker` itsef we should use `.close()`, because `.terminate()` is just available in main thread? The data sent is just a hex string, so I don't think it'd be a big problem. Can you explain your solution more?

Comment: @Teresa Yes, you are correct https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#dom-dedicatedworkerglobalscope-close . What is the `.length` of the string? Why do you create the `Worker` inside of the `Promise` constructor?

Comment: If `hex` is a hex string, why do you set the `src` of `image` element to `image/${hex}`?

Comment: `image/${hex}` contains the image

Comment: What do you mean by "contains the image"? Are you trying to set the `src` of the image to a `data URI` `data:[<media type>][;base64],<data>`?

Comment: The `data URI` scheme is `data:` protocol, then `MIME` type, e.g, `image/svg+xml`,  then `;`then optional `base64`, then `,` then plain text, encoded text or `base64` string, that is `<data>`. You are missing `data:` protocol, `MIME` type; not entirely sure what `hex` is; though if encoded properly, should render image. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: the image render is working, the problem is just on the worker

Comment: Have you included error handling and removed call to `.close()`? How do you know that image is rendering correctly if the browser crashes? It should be possible to reproduce what you are trying at plnkr http://plnkr.co. What is passed to `getData()` ? What is `.length` of the string `hex`?

Comment: Haven't removed the call to `.close()`, can you explain more, maybe with code, in your answer? I mentioned the problem in the question: _The problem is, when ran, it makes the browser crash. Even if it's not crashing, the performance is much slower than without using worker._ . It works in small images, but runs very slow. In slightly larger image, it crashes

Comment: Have you read the link to `data URI` scheme? _"Length limitations
Although Firefox supports data URIs of essentially unlimited length, browsers are not required to support any particular maximum length of data. For example, the Opera 11 browser limited data URIs to around 65000 characters."_

Comment: Will try to simulate what you are trying to achieve. That is, pass data in chunks to main thread. Another alternative is to post an `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob` representation of `hex` to main thread, instead of a string. What are the three parameters passed to `getData()`?

Comment: The URI data is 220 character maximum. The params of `getData()` are on the code above: `data` is image from canvas context, `x` and `y` are integer

Comment: 222 characters should not crash browser. Can you reproduce what you are trying at plnkr http://plnkr.co? There is an option at left panel to create files, where you can include `worker.js` and call from main thread. Its ok it browser crashes, here. Would probably substitute sending `Blob` to main thread instead of string, though am curious why chrome is crashing when posting a 220 character string?

Comment: @Teresa Is `html` needed? What function should be called to reproduce the effect that you described?

Comment: the server is in Node.js, I'm not sure if getting the svg from `hex` could be done. I also can't show all of the codes which means it couldn't be run straight forward... the `build()` function in class `Mosaic`

Comment: A server should not be needed to demonstrate issue described at Question. Can you reproduce the essential portion of the Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . That is, passing image data rendered at `canvas` to `Worker`? Where browser becomes slower and occasionally crashes?

Comment: I've included as much and as needed information as I can provide in the question. I've updated again the code in the question. I don't know which part causes the problem. What I know is when I don't use Worker, everything works fine

Comment: _"What I know is when I don't use Worker, everything works fine"_ Not using `Worker` would resolve Question, yes?  Not sure how to reproduce the issue you have described at OP?

Comment: In the problem description: _ImageUtil.getHex is a heavy function that needs to iterate every pixel of an image area area, so that's why I want to create it runs in the background and done in multithreading. The function is also independent, which I guess is a good candidate to put in the worker._ I would like to know the proper way to do this in `Worker`, that's why I posted the question... I've add desc about how to reproduce it

Comment: There are other issues with the script. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'window' of object '#<Window>'` , `ReferenceError: TILE_WIDTH is not defined(…)`. Is `#file-input` expecting an `svg` image, or any image type?

Comment: `TILE_WIDTH` and `TILE_HEIGHT` and stuffs are declared in another part of the code. The code works. `file-input` expects any image type

Comment: What should `TILE_WIDTH` and `TILE_HEIGHT` be set to? `TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
    at Mosaic.build (http://run.plnkr.co/ujC3O4V3Q2IrjHJ1/script.js:11:58)
    at loadImage.then (http://run.plnkr.co/ujC3O4V3Q2IrjHJ1/script.js:96:18)`

Comment: both could be set to int: `16`

Comment: Can you update plnkr to fill in the necessary portions so can reach point where data is posted to `Worker`?

Comment: Is the plnkr OK now?

Comment: No. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
    at Mosaic.build (http://run.plnkr.co/ujC3O4V3Q2IrjHJ1/script.js:9:58)
    at loadImage.then (http://run.plnkr.co/ujC3O4V3Q2IrjHJ1/script.js:95:18)` Do you need to pass the image to `build`?

Comment: added the constructor of Mosaic

Comment: `ReferenceError: options is not defined(…)`

Comment: You are calling `makeTile` within a nested `for` loop. Call `makeTile` after `for` loops. Actually, you are creating a new `Worker` at each call to `makeTile`. That is the issue. Push the results to an array then use `Promise.all()`

Comment: Create `Worker` outside of `makeTile`

Comment: You were creating 950 `Worker` instances. You need to rearrange your script to pass an array of promises to `worker.js`, once. At `worker.js` process the array, and return an array of `hex` values.

Comment: Can you move the solution to your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Teresa At a bare minimum, create logic which calls `let worker = new Worker('worker.js');` at most once.  That will solve the issue of the browser crashing. And passing an array of data to `postMessage`, where an array of data is expected back - at a single `message` event. There can be multiple message events without browser crashing; though are more than one message event needed to achieve expected result?

Comment: I use several workers now, and instead of posting a list of data to the worker, I send individual data. The point that I made too much `Worker` instance is the bullseye. Thanks a lot!